# Generate matrix given a list of lists

Tags: python, matrix, brute-force

I have to generate a matrix NxN where in each line every element is different and the elements go from 1 to N.
I have to find a matrix that contains some properties using brute-force so my idea is to generate a matrix and test the properties and if it doesn't pass I generate another one. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by each 'line'? column? row? both?

Comment: @L.Grozinger I mean row

Comment: so [1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3; 1, 2 3] (3 rows with elements 1, 2, 3) is valid?

Comment: @L.Grozinger exactly, but if it doesn't pass the tests I have to generate the next one for example [1,2,3;1,2,3;1,3,2]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `np.random.permutation(x)`. For example, for N=10:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 10
matrix = np.array([np.random.permutation(range(1,N+1)) for i in range(N)])
```

If you have to have a list of lists as a result, then you can add

```py
list_of_lists = matrix.tolist()
```

If you want to go through all possible matrices (as indicated in the comments), then you can write a generator that yields matrices, and [use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) `itertools.permutations` for going through row options, and `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` for going through row combination options.

```py
import itertools
def generate_new_matrix(N):
    # generate all possible rows
    rows = list(itertools.permutations(range(1,N+1)))
    # initiate combinations over possible rows
    for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(rows)), N):
        yield [list(rows[i]) for i in c]
```

You can then go through matrices as

```py
for matrix in generate_new_matrix(N):
   ....
```